# Addressing Matlab matrix with Index-matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am using the command `[A,idx] = sort(A)`, which sorts the matrix A columnwise, which is what I want. The `idx` matrix shows how each column of A has been sorted. Now if I try and access `B(idx)` MATLAB assumes I am referencing `B` in an absolute manner. This is however not what I want, I want the columns of `B` sorted with the same scheme `A` was sorted with.

I am therefore looking for a command that will index a matrix columnwise. Of course I can easily do this with a loop, but it seems like a pretty poor solution. I have also come up with this solution, but it's not very pretty

```
idx = idx+repmat(0:size(idx,1):size(idx,2)*size(idx,1)-1,size(idx,1),1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
A = randi([1 10],[5 4]);
[AA,idx] = sort(A);
```

Your solution is not bad, you could improve it a bit by replacing the REPMAT call with BSXFUN:

```
idx = bsxfun(@plus, idx, 0:size(idx,1):numel(idx)-1);
isequal(AA,A(idx))
```

Another alternative is to convert to linear indices using SUB2IND:

```
idx = sub2ind(size(idx), idx, repmat(1:size(idx,2),size(idx,1),1));
isequal(AA,A(idx))
```

Comment: thanks, I think I will use the bsxfun approach. I'm surprised that matlab doesn't have a built in function for this.